# обясните мне этот код пж

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap, sass

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
         $('#header').addClass('header-scrolled');
     }
     else {
         $('#header').removeClass('header-scrolled');
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Здесь написано:

При событии прокрутки окна добавить блоку id = "header" класс "header-scrolled".
В случае отсутствия прокрутки удалить этот класс "header-scrolled".

Обычно такое код используется для показа/сокрытия некоторых элементов при прокрутке страницы. Например кнопка "Позвоните нам" при прокрутке страницы перемещается в некое постоянно видимое место. Для добавляемого класса просто пишутся дополнительные стили.